# RXJava Android make multiple calls with different lengths

Tags: android, retrofit, rx-java, rx-android

I need to get the camera ID from the server, then get the events of this camera by ID, and at the end get the image by ID.
Then, all this needs to be combined into a UI post {Camera name - image url - it events}
For example, we might have 5 camera names, 30 event IDs (6 for one camera name) and 30 url.
I tried to use zip to combine Observable api calls that (separately) get the camera name, event id and image url. But as I understand it does not work normally due to the fact that zip cannot properly match 5 names and 30 IDs
Tell me what can be used for this?

```
 GetApiMethods getApiMethods = NetworkService.getInstance().createService(GetApiMethods.class);
    Observable<Camera> cameras = getCamera();
    Observable<Event> events = getEvents();
    Observable<Post> combined = Observable.zip(cameras, events, (camera, event) -> new Post(camera.getDisplayName(),"null",event.getType()));


    public LiveData<String> CameraRequests() {
        combined.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .concatMap(Observable::fromArray)
                .subscribe(new Observer<Post>() {

                    @Override
                    public void onSubscribe(@NonNull Disposable d) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onNext(@NonNull Post post) {
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(@NonNull Throwable e) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onComplete() {

                    }
                });

        return liveData;
    }

    public Observable<Event> getEvents() {
        return Observable.create(allEvents -> getApiMethods.getCameras()
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .concatMap(Observable::fromIterable)
                .concatMap(Observable::fromIterable)
                .concatMap(camera -> getApiMethods.getEvents(camera.getAccessPoint().replace("hosts", "")))
                .concatMap(Observable::fromIterable)
                .map(Event::getId)
                .subscribe(new Observer<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSubscribe(@NonNull Disposable d) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onNext(@NonNull String event) {
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(@NonNull Throwable e) {
                        Log.d("RXJAVA1", String.valueOf(e));
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onComplete() {

                    }
                })
        );

    }



    public Observable<Camera> getCamera() {

        return Observable.create(cameras1 -> getApiMethods.getCameras()
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .concatMap(Observable::fromIterable)
                .map(Camera::getDisplayName)
                .subscribe(new Observer<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSubscribe(@NonNull Disposable d) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onNext(@NonNull String s) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(@NonNull Throwable e) {
                        Log.d("RXJAVA", String.valueOf(e));
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onComplete() {
                        

                    }
                })

        );

    }
```

Comment: @MikkelT Thank you! But I have no problem with Livedata, only with RXJava

Comment: omg Im sorry, I must have replied to the wrong thread

Comment: Can you add the code of what you tried so far?

Comment: @DatPhamTat Hello! I have attached the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems pretty forward to me if using `flatMap`:

```
Observable<Post> getPostsObservable() {
        return getCameras().flatMap(camera ->
                // for each camera, build observable to get events
                getEvents(camera.accessPoint).flatMap(event ->
                        // for each event, build observable to get imageUrl
                        getImageUrl(event.id).map(imageUrl ->
                                // combine camera, event and imageUrl in current rx-chain
                                new Post(camera, event, imageUrl)
                        )
                )
        );
    }
```

You may have to tweak your code a little bit more, like simplifying your `getCameras` and `getEvents` methods. You can check out the demo below that mimics your app, to better understand how it works and what to rework. If calling the `getPosts` method, you should see in logcat that the Posts are being correctly created and received.

```
import android.util.Log;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import io.reactivex.Observable;
import io.reactivex.Observer;
import io.reactivex.disposables.Disposable;
import io.reactivex.schedulers.Schedulers;

public class RxDemo {
    // your Camera class
    public class Camera {
        private final String accessPoint;

        public Camera(String accessPoint) {
            this.accessPoint = accessPoint;
        }

        public String getAccessPoint() {
            return accessPoint;
        }
    }

    // your Event class
    public class Event {
        private final String id;

        public Event(String id) {
            this.id = id;
        }

        public String getId() {
            return id;
        }
    }

    // your Post class
    public class Post {
        private final Camera camera;
        private final Event event;
        private final String imageUrl;

        public Post(Camera camera, Event event, String imageUrl) {
            this.camera = camera;
            this.event = event;
            this.imageUrl = imageUrl;
        }

        public Camera getCamera() {
            return camera;
        }

        public Event getEvent() {
            return event;
        }

        public String getImageUrl() {
            return imageUrl;
        }

        @NonNull
        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "camera: " + camera.accessPoint + "; event: " + event.id + "; imageUrl: " + imageUrl;
        }
    }

    // mocked getApiMethods.getCameras(), return 5 mocked cameras
    private Observable<List<Camera>> apiGetCameras() {
        List<Camera> cameras = new ArrayList<>();
        cameras.add(new Camera("cam_1"));
        cameras.add(new Camera("cam_2"));
        cameras.add(new Camera("cam_3"));
        cameras.add(new Camera("cam_4"));
        cameras.add(new Camera("cam_5"));
        return Observable.just(cameras);
    }

    // mocked getApiMethods.getEvents, return 6 mocked events with cameraId postFix
    private Observable<List<Event>> apiGetEvents(String cameraId) {
        List<Event> events = new ArrayList<>();
        events.add(new Event("event_1_" + cameraId));
        events.add(new Event("event_2_" + cameraId));
        events.add(new Event("event_3_" + cameraId));
        events.add(new Event("event_4_" + cameraId));
        events.add(new Event("event_5_" + cameraId));
        events.add(new Event("event_6_" + cameraId));
        return Observable.just(events);
    }

    // mocked getApiMethods.getImageUrl
    private Observable<String> apiGetImageUrl(String eventId) {
        return Observable.just("http://my.domain.com/" + eventId + ".png");
    }

    public Observable<Camera> getCameras() {
        return apiGetCameras().concatMapIterable(cam -> cam);
    }

    public Observable<Event> getEvents(String cameraId) {
        return apiGetEvents(cameraId).concatMapIterable(event -> event);
    }

    // build observable that emits posts
    private Observable<Post> getPostsObservable() {
        return getCameras().flatMap(camera ->
                // for each camera, build observable to get events
                getEvents(camera.accessPoint).flatMap(event ->
                        // for each event, build observable to get imageUrl
                        apiGetImageUrl(event.id).map(imageUrl ->
                                // combine camera, event and imageUrl in current rx-chain
                                new Post(camera, event, imageUrl)
                        )
                )
        );
    }

    // call this in your activity/fragment/viewModel to get the posts
    public void getPosts() {
        getPostsObservable()
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .subscribe(new Observer<Post>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSubscribe(@NonNull Disposable d) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onNext(@NonNull Post post) {
                        Log.d("AAAA", post.toString());
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(@NonNull Throwable e) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onComplete() {

                    }
                });
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! This completely solved my problem.
If possible, could you tell me how I can add to this downloading photos from the server based on event.getID? (without code, just theory)

Comment: Not sure how your download logic looks like, but in the `onNext` callback inside `getPosts` you have all information needed for the post, including the `imageUrl`, so you can execute a download there. Say your download function is named `public void downloadImage(String imageUrl)`, then you would call it inside `onNext` callback, using `post.imageUrl` as parameter.

Comment: If my comment did not answer your question about image download then maybe create a new question with code (what you tried / what you thought would work) and further explanation. It will be easier for me to help you if I understood your problem better.

Comment: Thank's! New question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68619492/rxjava-retrofit-download-jpeg

Comment: Sorry to ask again, but `return cameras.concatMap(camera ->
                getArchive().concatMap(
                        archive -> getEvents(archive.getAccessPoint().replace("hosts", "")).flatMap(event -> getdetectorImage(archive.getAccessPoint().replace("hosts", ""), event.getTimestamp(), event.getId()).map(image -> new Post(camera.getDisplayName(), image.byteStream(), event.getType()))
                        )));` does not work quite correctly, the names of the cameras are displayed as if they were random.What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I don't really understand your comment. There's no `getArchive()` in the original question. Is your comment related to your newly created question? I haven't seen your new question yet, as I am working during the week, I have little free time. I will look at it later.