# RXJava Retrofit download jpeg

Tags: android, retrofit, rx-java

I have api get request

```
 @GET ("/archive/media{videoSourceId}/{time}/")
    Observable<ResponseBody> getDetectorImage (@Path(value = "videoSourceId", encoded = true) String videoSourceId,@Path(value = "time", encoded = true) String time);
```

To download an image from the server

Server respons byte's array

```
cache-control: no-cache
connection: Close
content-length: 25338
content-type: image/jpeg
x-video-original-time: 20210802T031351.895000
```

I try this code

```
 private Observable<Post> getPostsObservable() {
        return cameras.flatMap(camera ->
                getArchive().flatMap(
                        archive -> getEvents(archive.getAccessPoint().replace("hosts", "")).flatMap(event -> getdetectorImage(archive.getAccessPoint().replace("hosts", ""),event.getTimestamp(),event.getId()).map(image -> new Post(camera.getDisplayName(),event.getId(),event.getType()))
                )));

    }
public Observable<Event> getEvents(String cameraName) {
        return getApiMethods.getEvents(cameraName).concatMapIterable(events -> events);

    }

    public Observable<Archive> getArchive() {
        return getApiMethods.getCameras().concatMap(Observable::fromIterable)
                .concatMap(Observable::fromIterable)
                .map(archive -> archive);
    }

    public Observable<Camera> getCamera() {

        return getApiMethods.getCameras().concatMap(Observable::fromIterable)
                .map(camera -> camera);
    }

    public Observable<ResponseBody> getdetectorImage(String cameraId, String timestamp, String archiveID) {
        return getApiMethods.getDetectorImage(cameraId, timestamp)
                .doOnNext(responseBody -> {
                    Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(responseBody.byteStream());
                    ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                    bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, stream);
                    byte[] byteArray = stream.toByteArray();

                    FileOutputStream fileOuputStream =
                            new FileOutputStream(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory());
                    fileOuputStream.write(byteArray);
                    fileOuputStream.close();
                });
    }
```

But i have a error

W/System.err: Caused by: retrofit2.adapter.rxjava3.HttpException: HTTP 403 Fobidden

Comment: The task is to store an image with the file name = event.getID
Then in Post I pass (camera.getDisplayName(), event.getId(), event.getType())
And in my RecyclerView Adapter I will get images by even.getID and insert them into ImageViev

Comment: The HTTP 403 Forbidden client error status response code indicates that the server understood the request but refuses to authorize it. Seems like the URL that u r accessing is unauthorized. Any way for caching and displaying images ill suggest u to use glide library

Comment: @NidhinPrathap Hello! I add header to my request with Basic auth token. This request work in https://reqbin.com/ and from browser URL. Another api Get request on this server wok great in my app.

Comment: Then ill suggest you check with the server team where its going wrong

Comment: sometimes i get `Caused by: retrofit2.adapter.rxjava3.HttpException: HTTP 403 Fobidden`, sometimes `HTTP FAILED: java.net.SocketException: Socket closed`